# What is the difference between this.value and $(this).val()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wondering what is the difference between `this.value` and `$(this).val()` in jQuery? I realised when I console.log `this.value` and console.log `$(this).val()`, the results for each of them are different which meant that `this.value`≠`$(this).val()`

Comment: `this.value` is vanilla javascript, `$(this).val()` is jQuery

Answer (score 4):

When you're calling `.val()` with no arguments, the result is *almost always* the same. You can see the source code [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js), search for `val: function( value ) {`:

```
val: function( value ) {
    var hooks, ret, valueIsFunction,
        elem = this[ 0 ];

    if ( !arguments.length ) {
        if ( elem ) {
            hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] ||
                jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

            if ( hooks &&
                "get" in hooks &&
                ( ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" ) ) !== undefined
            ) {
                return ret;
            }

            ret = elem.value;

            // Handle most common string cases
            if ( typeof ret === "string" ) {
                return ret.replace( rreturn, "" );
            }

            // Handle cases where value is null/undef or number
            return ret == null ? "" : ret;
        }

        return;
    }
    // other logic for when there are arguments
```

If the element definitely exists, and there are no `valHooks`, then the only *substantive* line that will really do anything is

```
ret = elem.value;
```

which will then be returned at the end.

Note that you can call `.val()` on a jQuery collection which contains *no* elements, in which case the empty string will be returned. (in contrast, trying to access the `.value` of a non-existent element will throw an error)

The `valHooks` are used to retrieve the value of certain elements which can't be accessed via `.value`, like `<select>`s, but this only has relevance for extremely ancient obsolete browsers - *or* if the script-writer has manually assigned to properties of `$.valHooks`.

Answer (score 3):

> Just wondering what is the difference between this.value and $(this).val() in jQuery?

It depends on the context.  When used correctly, they are exactly the same **except for textareas**:

> At present, using .val() on  elements strips carriage return characters from the browser-reported value. When this value is sent to the server via XHR, however, carriage returns are preserved (or added by browsers which do not include them in the raw value).

I think this really is *begs the question*:

> why does .val() exist if .value does the same thing.

This is because when you use jQuery to select an element `$('#myinput')`, you are returned an array of HtmlElements, not a single element.  In this case the code would have to index an element to get value using the property `('#myinput')[0].value = ('#myinput').val()`.  So `val()` is a nice shortcut, and provides a *kind of error handling* in certain cases.

> When the first element in the collection is a select-multiple (i.e., a select element with the multiple attribute set), .val() returns an array containing the value of each selected option. As of jQuery 3.0, if no options are selected, it returns an empty array; prior to jQuery 3.0, it returns null.

When used with a jQuery selector they definitely aren't the same thing.

Comment: Yep, `var rreturn = /\r/g;` But is there a way for a textarea's `.value` to include a linefeed in the first place? I tried `t.value = '\r\n\r\n'` and then `t.value.includes('\r')` -> `false`. Was it a thing in old browsers?

Comment: It may be a relic of previous version left in the [.val() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/val/).